# Pattern matching for dates/times?

Tags: java, date

Is there any language that expresses matching a particular date/time pattern in a similar way to regexes or crontabs to the current time?

For example say I want to either trigger or check if I am in the time window on demand that is anything occurring on the first day of the month; any time that is a mutliple of 5 minutes plus a 1 minute offset; any leap year etc... I suspect such a thing does not exist and you can be certain any search that looks for it is going to be about matching date string representations with regexes.

I'm thinking a cron like expression is probably the best there is out there. I'm looking for Java implementations in particular if anyone knows of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://docjar.com/docs/api/org/quartz/CronExpression.html

This is available as a part of quartz-scheduler.

Refer: http://docjar.com/docs/api/org/quartz/CronExpression.html#isSatisfiedBy(Date)

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with this. Looks like isSatisfiedBy(Date) would achieve what I want. Suggest you update your answer to include that for other people.